# Ordinary Differential Equation or Open Dynamics Engine?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

The current description for the [ode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ode) tag reads as follows:

> ODE (ordinary differential equation) is a differential equation where the unknown function only has one independent variable and its derivatives.

However, several questions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528237/ode-body-destruction-invalid-operation-for-locked-space) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262052/fps-problen-in-grsim) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010610/how-can-i-get-body-position-from-ode-engine)) are using it to refer to the [Open Dynamics Engine](http://ode.org) instead.

I'd suggest that we create a new tag, such as [libode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libode) or [open-dynamics-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-dynamics-engine), and re-tag any questions related to the Open Dynamics Engine to disambiguate them.

I'm not sure whether anything needs to be done with the [ode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ode) tag itself; perhaps it could be re-purposed for questions related to the [Open Dark Engine](https://github.com/volca02/openDarkEngine)? ;)

Comment: There is also Apache ODE (Orchestration Director Engine)

Comment: A [tla] tag jumps to mind.  Contextual tag for all Three Letter Acronym questions.  345 questions will take you a while, take a month to chip away at it.

Comment: @HansPassant 345 is the total of [ode] tag; the majority of questions there are tagged correctly (are about the ordinary differential equations), so the scale of proposed retagging is not that large.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags

Answer (score -10):

I think it's unnecessary. People just need to read the description of the tag and they will come to know that it is or is not the right tag for them. If they are too lazy to do that then it's their fault if they don't get answers to their posts because it is in the wrong area.

Comment: Misused tags don't only harm the asker, but also tag followers and future searchers.

Comment: Like I said, people need to read. It's a basic skill. Don't make it easier for them not to read. You will increase the illiteracy rate ;).

Comment: If a reader has to read the question for [tag] context, it nearly defeats the purpose of tagging it in the first place

Comment: We've learned from the countless [tags with wikis saying "DO NOT USE"](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/266086/tags-which-should-not-be-used) (which get new answers regularly) that people don't always read them. Bad tagging affects more than just the person asking the question, and ambiguous tags just make the problem even worse.

Comment: Assume for a minute that most people don't read the tag description, and that wishing they do won't change that. Then, as the problem is still present, it's up to us to make it clearer.

Comment: [Section 2.3 of "metacrap" comes to mind](http://www.well.com/~doctorow/metacrap.htm#2.3)

Comment: @Emrakul, that is the dumbest assumption I have ever read. Normal people don't go through life staring blankly at things.

Comment: @I.K. I [wish](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6806067) I [were](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6949811) as [optimistic](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6852858) as you.

Comment: Have any of you done any statistical analysis on how many posts get tagged with the wrong tags? If it is a minuscule percentage then why bother going through with your proposition? Out of all the posts in SO, I ask you how many were tagged with the wrong tags. If you can give me a qualified and scientific response then we can proceed forward; make some measurements. A few posts here and there doesn't warrant what you are proposing. Does no one believe in science and common-sense anymore?

Comment: The point of this question is that there *aren't* any tags for the Open Dynamics Engine at the moment, so it's *not possible* to tag those questions correctly. (We do have a tag for [tag:apache-ode] tag, though).

Comment: yes go ahead and create a tag for that but don't go around hacking other tags just because people don't read the tag name and/or the associated description